# Details on latex' math alphabets

Tags: math-mode

I understand a bit how the nfss work for text fonts, but I have a hard time following the code in `latex.ltx` for math fonts (and the documentation in `source2e.pdf` is a bit sparse there). Hence I have some questions:

If I recursively look at the definition of eg `\mathcal` via `latexdef` I get

```
\mathcal : macro:->\relax \ifmmode \else \non@alpherr \mathcal  \fi \use@mathgroup \M@OMS \symsymbols
\use@mathgroup: macro:#1#2->\relax \ifmmode \math@bgroup \expandafter \ifx \csname M@\f@encoding \endcsname #1\else #1\fi \mathgroup #2\relax \expandafter \math@egroup \fi 
\mathgroup: \fam
```

From my understanding `\T@OMS` and `\M@OMS` respectively are the loading code specified in 
`\DeclareFontEncoding {encoding} {text-settings} {math-settings}` and by default do nothing.

So essentially in math mode `\mathcal` switches to `\M@OMS` is `OMS` was not the current encoding already and uses the math family encoded by `\symsymbols`, which makes sense because `\mathcal` is defined via
`\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathcal}{symbols}`.

For `\mathit` this is essentially the same once it has been used, before it is
`\select@group \mathit  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmr/m/it` and a mathgroup with this font is created when `\mathit` is first used.

But I am missing something. For instance in `\mathrm{ab-de}` the `-` is still typeset as an operator rather than in the `rm` font. So I am guessing `\mathrm` only change the mathcode of some letters to use the corresponding `symoprators` math family, but not all of them, and I cannot find where in the source.

Second question: since `\mathrm` is defined via `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathrm}{operators}` what happen if we do both a `\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}...` and a `\SetMathAlphabet\mathrm{bold}...`?
Are these equivalent, both changing the `\symoperators` math group in math version bold?

Comment: Welcome to Tex StackExchange. You might want to look up what the TeX primitive \fam does in math mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the work of `\mathrm` eventually boils down to do `\fam=n`, where `n` stands for a one-byte integer (from 0 to 15), *in a group*. The default is 0, because `\mathrm` is defined via

```
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathrm}{operators}
```

and `fontmath.ltx` has

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
```

as its *first* declaration of a symbol font. Such declarations can later be overridden by font packages, but `operators` will always point to math family 0.

During the execution of `\mathrm` there is *no* mathcode change. It's a primitive feature of TeX that if a character has a mathcode `"7xyz` (the most significant byte is 7), then TeX will typeset the character in slot `"yz` of the font in the current math family, if the current value of `\fam` is between 0 and 15. Otherwise the character will use the font in math family `"x`.

Side note: LaTeX defines `\mathgroup` as an alias for `\fam`.

Indeed, we have in `fontmath.ltx`

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{a}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`a}
```

and similarly for the other letters. This is LaTeX lingo for the corresponding declaration in plain TeX

```
\mathcode`a="7197
```

because the declaration for `letters` is the second in `fontmath.ltx`, so corresponding to math family 1.

Since no math code is changed and `-` is declared as

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{-}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"00}
```

which corresponds to `` \mathcode`-="2300 ``, it will not be affected by the current value of `\fam`.

The `\operatorname` macro of `amsmath` does indeed change math codes so that `-` appears as a real hyphen.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very clear explanation. This explains why `\mathrm` only affects symbols of type `\mathalpha`. I should really read the TeX book someday. By the way I think you meant that `letters` corresponds to math family 1.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning my second question:

> Second question: since \mathrm is defined via \DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathrm}{operators} what happen if we do both a \SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}... and a \SetMathAlphabet\mathrm{bold}...? Are these equivalent, both changing the \symoperators math group in math version bold?

I can now answer. Using `\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}...` update the font for the operator symbol in bold version, and keeps the link between `\mathrm` and `operators`. However, doing `\SetMathAlphabet\mathrm{bold}...` makes `\mathrm` a new (standard) math alphabet. Indeed in this case the following snippet of `SetMathAlphabet@` gets executed:

```
       \edef\reserved@a{% 
         \noexpand\in@{\string\use@mathgroup}{\meaning#4}}%
       \reserved@a
       \ifin@ % if we were a symbol font alphabet
         \def\reserved@b##1\use@mathgroup##2##3{%
             \def\reserved@b{##3}\def\reserved@c{##2}}%
         \expandafter\reserved@b#4% reserved@b now holds the value of the symbol math group, and reserved@c is M@enc
         \begingroup
           \def\install@mathalphabet##1##2{%
               \addto@hook\toks@{\install@mathalphabet##1{##2}}%
               }% we copy the existing alphabets
            \def\getanddefine@fonts##1##2{% we copy the existing symbol fonts
              \addto@hook\toks@{\getanddefine@fonts##1##2}%
              \ifnum##1=\reserved@b %if the symbol font is the one we are replacing, use it to set up the font of our new alphabet
                 \expandafter
                 \addto@hook\expandafter\toks@
                 \expandafter{\expandafter\install@mathalphabet
                 \expandafter#4\expandafter
                       {\expandafter\select@group\expandafter
                         #4\reserved@c##2}}%
              \fi
                      }%
           \def\version@elt##1{%
               \toks@{}%
               ##1%
               \xdef##1{\the\toks@}%
              }%
           \version@list
         \endgroup
         \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\alpha@list\expandafter
             {\alpha@list
              \alpha@elt #4\no@alphabet@error \no@alphabet@error}%
         \gdef#4{\no@alphabet@error #5}% fake things :-)
         \SetMathAlphabet@{#1}{#2}{#3}#4#5% set up the font requested for this version
```

So we see that we get a new `\mathrm` standard alphabet, without default (ie `\no@alphabet@error`) but the existing fonts definition for `operators` in the current math version get copied for `\mathrm` (and of course the version specified in `SetMathAlphabet` gets updated).

Consider the result of `latexdef -o '\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{bold}{T1}{lmr}{xb}{sc}' 'mv@bold'`, we get `\install@mathalphabet \mathrm  {\select@group \mathrm  \M@T1 \T1/lmr/xb/sc }` as expected. More interesting, the result of `latexdef -o '\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{bold}{T1}{lmr}{xb}{sc}' 'mv@normal'` yields `\mathrm  {\select@group \mathrm  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmr/m/n }`. We see that the font for the new `\mathrm` alphabet in normal mode was copied from the value of the `operators` symbol font.